# Can't get JavaScript values to add properly

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to get my values from this form to add the way they should. I want all of these range inputs to add their values to one number.

Like for example:
range1 is 3
range2 is 2
range3 is 8
range4 is 5
so I want var txt=x+y+z+e; to be 18. But instead it's 3285.

How can I solve this problem? New to JavaScript

```
<form id="frm1" action="" onmouseup="sistetest()">
0<input class="blackandorange" type="range" id="range1" name="points" value="2" min="0" max="10">10<br>
0<input class="blackandorange" type="range" id="range2" name="points" value="2" min="0" max="10">10<br>
0<input class="blackandorange" type="range" id="range3" name="points" value="2" min="0" max="10">10<br>
0<input class="blackandorange" type="range" id="range4" name="points" value="2" min="0" max="10">10<br>
</form>

<script>
function sistetest()
{
var x = document.getElementById("range1").value;
var y = document.getElementById("range2").value;
var z = document.getElementById("range3").value;
var e = document.getElementById("range4").value;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x+y+z+e;
}
</script>
```

Comment: its giving you strings and concatenating them, parse them as ints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the strings to numbers:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Number(x)+Number(y)+Number(z)+Number(e);
```

Answer (score 1):

Values you get from the DOM like that are always **strings**. You have to force them to be numbers:

```
var x = +document.getElementById("range1").value;
var y = +document.getElementById("range2").value;
var z = +document.getElementById("range3").value;
var e = +document.getElementById("range4").value;
```

is one simple way.

The JavaScript `+` operator (the two-operand version) is tricky because it has meaning for both strings and numbers, *and* JavaScript rules actually *prefer* the string semantics over numeric semantics. That is, if you add a number to a string (or a string to a number), JavaScript converts the number to a string and performs a concatenation operation.

In this case, all you have are strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("range1").value);
```

By default, getElementById is treated as a string.  Therefore, you will need to convert it to an integer if you want to treat it as an integer.

Comment: In future, you might want to expand on this and actually explain *why* this is required rather than just posting the code with "etc".